# Laravel Delete row from database and List remaining rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a laravel web application and i would like to delete a row from my **formdata** table and after successful deletion i want to display remaining table rows with an deleted flash message.

please take a look in my code,

*Routes.php*

```
Route::get('manage-forms',array('as'=>'manage_forms','uses'=>'Nri@manage_forms'));
```

this route is listing the table rows(datas).

```
Route::get('delete/{id}',array('as'=>'delete_formdata','uses'=>'Nri@delete_form'));
```

this route is deleting existing one row and sending flash message to the above route.

*Controller ==>*

```
public function manage_forms()
{
    $form_data=Formdata::all();
    return View::make('manage_forms')->with('form_array',$form_data);
}

public function delete_form($id)
{

    $deleted=Formdata::find($id);
    $deleted->delete();

    return View::make('manage_forms')->with('message','the Data is deleted');
}
```

*View*
     Registered Form details

```
 <h2>Registered Form details</h2>

 @if(Session::has('message'))
 <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
 @endif
 <table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Mobile</td>

</tr>
@foreach($form_array as $form_view)
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$form_view->id}}">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$form_view->name}}"/>
    </td>

    <td>{{$form_view->mobile}}</td>
    <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('edit_formdata','Edit',array($form_view->id))}}</td>
    <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('view_formdata','View ',array($form_view->id))}}</td>
    <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('delete_formdata','Delete ',array($form_view->id))}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>


 <h2>{{HTML::linkRoute('test_session','Home')}}</h2>
```

Normally i points to **manage-forms** route, it displaying correct data from database & working fine.

but after deletion the browser showing me to error like below,

```
 Undefined variable: form_array (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\laravel2\app\views\manage_forms.blade.php)
```

it does not redirected to **manage-forms** route,

Anybody please help me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the **return Redirect::to('manage-forms')** to solve this issue,